# Vue router: how to pass data to default/ initial route

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-router, default

I have a vue router config set up like so:

```js
[
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: HomeComponent,
        props: true,
    },

    {
        name: 'detail',
        path: '/detail/:id',
        component: DetailComponent,
        props: true,
    }
]
```

The app containing this config performs the followin:

1. Queries an API for an object Foo
2. Displays a header with some info from Foo
3. Renders the default ("home") route with more info from Foo and a list of Bar items (contained in Foo) the user can click on to visit the detail route.

The problem is how can I pass the Foo data into the home route on first load? Since the API is part of the app component (as `this.api` - not a global) I can't hard code home's props inside the router config; and since I can't refer to this inside `beforeRouteEnter`, I can't use `this.api` to perform the request before routing to home.

I've tried:

1. Passing the Foo via `<router-view :foo="myFoo" />` - this had no effect whatsoever.
2. Re-routing to home via `this.$router.push()` or `this.$router.replace()` once Foo is loaded. This likewise had no effect, even with `$forceUpdate`.

I've considered:

1. Passing in data via `next()` inside the app's `beforeRouteLeave()` navigation guard. This strikes me as brittle at best since I will have to account for each specific route that gets a foo prop.
2. Any number of horrible hacks involving secret hidden routes and other magic.

I also suspect I will face the same issue with any deep linking, since the app will have to also obtain a foo before handing it off to the per-route component.

So. How can I pass data from the top-level app via a prop to any given route at page load time?

Comment: How is `api` assigned to `this` within your components? There should be nothing stopping you accessing `api` within `beforeRouteEnter`, you just need to know how

Comment: @Phil beforeRouteEnter isn't called on the app. How would you propose I call the app's api within the sub-component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how exactly you are getting the `Foo` object, but assuming you are getting it inside of a `mounted()` hook in `App.vue`, you could send it to the `Home` component via Vuex store:

## Method 1

### App.vue

```js
mounted () {
  this.foo = getFoo()
},
computed: {
  foo: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.foo
    },
    set (value) {
      // commit or dispatch the object to store
    }
  }
}
```

### Home.vue

```html
<div>{{foo}}</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  foo () {
    return this.$store.state.foo
  }
}
```

## Method 2 - using an eventBus

Create a file called `eventBus.js`:

### eventBus.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
export const eventBus = new Vue()
```

Import created eventBus in your `main.js` where you import Vue and add it to Vue prototype if you want to make it globaly available:

### Main.js

```js
import { eventBus } from './eventBus'

Vue.prototype.$eventBus = eventBus
```

### App.vue

```js
mounted () {
  this.foo = getFoo()
  // Send foo via event bus
  this.$eventBus.$emit('transferFoo', this.foo)
}
```

### Home.vue

```html
<div>{{foo}}</div>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    foo: {}
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.$eventBus.$on('transferFoo', data => {
    this.foo = data
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems like adding a non-trivial dependency just to pass data to a component.. just seems like that's sub-optimal, and feels wrong.

Comment: @tbm I updated the answer and added another method, does that work for you?

Comment: this works (although I used $root instead of a separate event bus). Sad that "props is the way to pass data from parent to child" and "emit is how to pass data from child to parent" and yet here we are subverting those protocols. Still, it works, and if it goes against the platform's design, well that's on the designers.

Comment: Since foo is now inside data, it can't be passed via props.. meaning <router-link>s don't work, thus rendering a nav bar somewhat useless.

Comment: @tbm you don't have to put it in `data`, you can put it anywhere. I cannot see your code so I gave you a generic example, modify it according to your needs

Comment: Good point. I wrote that after a long unsatisfying day of coding :/

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since it spurred me to a solution, which is to use a prop value if set, otherwise a data item, and set the empty one from the other in mounted().

Comment: @tbm I'm glad it helped you find the solution